# How to check email validation in js with database

Tags: php, codeigniter, duplicates, email-validation

I am trying to avoid adding duplicate email addresses in a MySQL database. Is there any javascript way to check without reload? Like in the Gmail sign-in form?

Comment: You need to use Ajax.

Comment: Use AJAX to check Duplicate Email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use validate library : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote

your javascript :

```
$("#yourFormId").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "checkmail.php",
                    type: "post"
                 }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please Enter Email!",
                email: "This is not a valid email!",
                remote: "Email already in use!"
            }
        }
    });
```

checkmail.php :

```
<?php
$registeredEmails = array('test1@test.com', 'test2@test.com', 'test3@test.com');

$requestedEmail  = $_POST['email'];

if( in_array($requestedEmail, $registeredEmails) ){
    echo 'false';
}
else{
    echo 'true';
}
?>
```

and you can search in mysql posted email adress instead of $registeredEmails array :)

Comment: val_email: {
                        required: true,
      email:true,
      remote: {
                     url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/check_email') ?>",
                    type: "post"
                 }
                    },    is there any mistake in this???